# Can't move Objects just a little bit

Tags: modeling

When I want to move sth or to scale an object, I can't move it just a little bit, it jumps to certain positions and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you've got Snap set to Increment... uncheck this button

[image]

*During* transformations:

Invert the Snap button's state by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Gear down transformations, either in the numerical field, or in the 3D view, by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.